# SQLite date comparison weirdness

Tags: sqlite, date, comparison

I have an SQLite database where I'm trying to retrieve all rows with a deadline (created as DATETIME, typeof(deadline) returns text) after today. Here's the deadlines matched against today's date:

```
sqlite> SELECT deadline, Date('now') FROM confs;
2016-08-28|2016-07-05
2016-06-30|2016-07-05
...
```

Now if I try to select dates beyond today:

```
sqlite> SELECT deadline FROM confs WHERE deadline > Date('now')
sqlite>
```

no rows are returned. On the other hand,

```
sqlite> SELECT deadline, Date('now') FROM confs WHERE deadline < Date('now');
2016-08-28|2016-07-05
2016-06-30|2016-07-05
...
```

I've tried:

- creating the table with "deadline" of type text - no success, same result.
- casting either deadline or Date('now') as text - no success, same result.
- casting both deadline and Date('now') as text - no success, same result.
- using WHERE deadline > '2016-07-05' - no success, same result.
- using TimBiegelsen's suggestion: WHERE deadline > STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d', 'now') - no success, same result.

I think that the problem is related to the type of deadline, but that's a guess.

The goal is to have a table with one column containing dates, where I can select dates after Date('now'). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: created as DATETIME NOT NULL.
SELECT typeof(deadline) FROM confs returns 'text'

Comment: Note: `select deadline from confs where deadline = '2016-08-28';` doesn't return any rows - so there's probably a problem with the values or types in that column.

Comment: Your `deadline` column is in a weird format.  Try using `STRFTIME(deadline)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, silly me.
Turns out that I made a data entry error: the deadlines start with a space.